# animate div while changing class

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a simple boxes that changes position on click. so I have three boxes, I can only choose the second and third box, because I want to switch selected box the the first one. I manage to switch them by replacing the their class, my problem is I dont know how to add a animation that they are switching place.

Hope you help me.

thanks.

```js
$('.container .card').click(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('center')) {
    $('.card.left').removeClass('left').addClass('center');
    $(this).removeClass('center').addClass('left');
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('right')) {
    $('.card.left').removeClass('left').addClass('right');
    $(this).removeClass('right').addClass('left');
  }

});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.center {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}

.card.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.card.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.card.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card left green"></div>
  <div class="card center blue"></div>
  <div class="card right red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact, you are changing DIVs style (background-color) instead of their position. It's not possible to add animate on them. Try another way to move them and have a look how css' animation works

Comment: Add and remove class(es) to elements while animating all style changes. https://jqueryui.com/switchClass/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change all of your CSS positioning to be based on `left`, you could then add a [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to the `.card` to animate it any time `left` changes.

[`translateX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX) allows you to move an element side-to-side *by a percentage of its own width*. This gives us the ability to right-align and center-align without the need for `right`.

```js
$('.container .card').click(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('center')) {
    $('.card.left').removeClass('left').addClass('center');
    $(this).removeClass('center').addClass('left');
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('right')) {
    $('.card.left').removeClass('left').addClass('right');
    $(this).removeClass('right').addClass('left');
  }

});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  transition: 0.5s all; /* Add a half-second transition */
}

.left {
  left: 0; 
}

.center {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.right {
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.card.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.card.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.card.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card left green"></div>
  <div class="card center blue"></div>
  <div class="card right red"></div>
</div>
```